# Syxtax error on component declaration

Tags: vhdl

The following code is throwing `Error: /home/project/path/dual_mux.vhd(11): near "component": syntax error`:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

--entity
entity dual_mux is 
    port(A, B, C : in STD_LOGIC;
         X, Y : out STD_LOGIC);
end dual_mux;

--mux as a component
component mux is  --line 11
    port(D: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
         S: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
         Y: out STD_LOGIC);
end component mux;

architecture dual_mux_arch of dual_mux is
    component mux;
    
    signal Dx_aux, Dy_aux: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal S_aux: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0) := "00";

    begin
    mux_x: mux port map(D=>Dx_aux, S=>S_aux, Y=>X);

    mux_y: mux port map(D=>Dy_aux, S=>S_aux, Y=>Y);

    S_aux <= A&B;
    
    Dx_aux(0)<= "0";
    Dx_aux(1)<= C;
    Dx_aux(2)<= not(C);
    Dx_aux(3)<= "1";

    Dy_aux(0)<= "1";
    Dy_aux(1)<= not(C);
    Dy_aux(2)<= "0";
    Dy_aux(3)<= C;

end dual_mux_arch;
```

Comment: A component declaration can only be a block declarative item in a block declarative part (in an architecture or a block statement) or as a package declarative item in a package declaration. Your component declaration is found between primary design unit entity dual_mux and it's architecture secondary design unit dual_mux_arch, causing the syntax error.

Comment: There are four place where string literals of length one are used in places of character literals (e.g. "0" and "1" should be '0' and '1'). These produce semantic errors.

Comment: Yes, I had made these changes on the answer but forgot to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the component must be declared and specified **inside** of the architecture, and not outside like I was doing it. Also, changed from double quotes (" ") to single quotes (' ') on assignment of character literals. Upon making these changes, the code compiled gracefully. This is the corrected code:

```vhdl
entity dual_mux is 
    port(A, B, C: in STD_LOGIC;
         X, Y: out STD_LOGIC);
end dual_mux;

architecture dual_mux_arch of dual_mux is
    component mux is
        port(D: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
            S: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
            Y: out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    
    signal Dx_aux, Dy_aux: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal S_aux: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0) := "00";

        begin
            mux_x: mux port map(D=>Dx_aux, S=>S_aux, Y=>X);

            mux_y: mux port map(D=>Dy_aux, S=>S_aux, Y=>Y);

            S_aux <= A&B;
    
            Dx_aux(0)<= '0';
            Dx_aux(1)<= C;
            Dx_aux(2)<= not(C);
            Dx_aux(3)<= '1';

            Dy_aux(0)<= '1';
            Dy_aux(1)<= not(C);
            Dy_aux(2)<= '1';
            Dy_aux(3)<= C;

end dual_mux_arch;
```